# What's the equivalent of `cpp -dD` for clang?

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

If I want to find out what implicit preprocessor defines gcc gives me, I can type `echo "" | cpp -dD`. Does anyone know what the equivalent for clang is?

Comment: `gcc -dD -E -` seems to give the same as `gcc -dM -E -` too, so...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
clang -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

will list all the preprocessor definitions for clang.

Comment: Indeed, and it should be mentioned that this is the *correct* way to do it with gcc too.

Answer (score 9):

clang "dumping processor state" options are defined [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#dumping-preprocessor-state). The option you are looking for is `-dM`, so you'll run:

```
clang -dM -E -
```

To trigger execution, you then need to terminate the manual input:

- For Windows: <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- For Unix: <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

Otherwise, directly execute:

- For Windows: `clang -dM -E - < NUL`
- For Unix: `clang -dM -E - < /dev/null`